# Visual Studio Code source control full of 'changes' I was not aware of

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control, source-control-explorer

How do I get rid of these **'changes'** on Visual Studio Code? There are over thousands of files and I was not aware of these changes since I installed vs code on my MacBook. I tried `git reset --hard` on the terminal, but nothing has happened. I also do not recall having these files on my laptop and VS Code cannot even open these files. VS Code also failed to notify me of these **'changes'**. Whenever I try to delete all the files, it says `git: fatal: you are on a branch yet to be born`

*See screenshot below:*

[image]

Comment: which folder is open in VSC, in this folder is a `.git` folder, think before deleting this `.git` folder

Comment: @rioV8 I dont see a ```.git``` folder here. Mostly python, java, html, css, .xml files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All of these "changes" are most likely do to you initializing git in a folder with lots of settings and configuration folders.** For example, in the screenshot, I can see that most of the "changes" are from `.eclipse` folder, a folder Eclipse uses to store configurations. You usually cannot see these folders, because they are "hidden" folders.

### Solution 1

**The first solution is to add a `.gitignore` file**, to ignore all of those unnecessary folders. To do this, just add a file named `.gitignore` to the current folder. Then in that file, put a list of all of the folders to be ignored. For example(Go through the list of "changes" and add more folders):

```
/.eclipse
```

### Solution 2

**The other solution to seeing these changes is just deleting the `.git` folder.** You can't see this folder by default, because it is a hidden folder. To see this, you have to go to Finder, and press **`Command + Shift + .`**. After you see the `.git` folder, you can just delete it. The changes should now go away.

Comment: There are also `/Users/alwin/....` files and a lot of `~/.eclipse/...` files, does he has a `.git` folder in his home directory, and he also has there a lot of his Python and HTML files.....

Comment: Or you could rename `.git` folder as `[delete].git`, works for me! :-)